# Remove files from queue on add

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp's file uploader. I want to make it so that users can only upload a single file (I can't use `maxNumberOfFiles` because I'm not using the UI plugin).

How can I make it so that when the user selects a new image to upload, it removes the file that was previously in the queue, and then adds the new image file into the queue for upload?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function(e, data) {
        var uploadErrors = [];
        var acceptFileTypes = /^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i;

        if (data.originalFiles[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.originalFiles[0]['type'])) {
            uploadErrors.push('Invalid file type.');
        } else if (data.originalFiles[0]['size'] > 1000000) {
            uploadErrors.push('Image over size.');
        }

        if (uploadErrors.length > 0) {
            $('.errors').html(uploadErrors);
        } else {
            data.submit();
        }                    
    },
    progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    }
});
```

Comment: do you have a button to trigger the upload?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate files array `data.files` / `data.originalFiles` after `add` action, unset file by index like:

```
data.files = $.grep( data.files, function( element, index ) {
    return index == 0;
    // or
    // return $.inArray(i, error_uploads_indexes) ==-1; // where error_uploads_indexes is array with files indexes You want to remove
});
// ...
data.submit();
```

and You can set `singleFileUploads: false` if You can.